# Magento2 override aroundExecute method

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override the method aroundExecute.

```
<type name="Magento\InventoryConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Sales\GetSkuFromOrderItem">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="X_Y_GetSkuFromOrderItem" sortOrder="10" type="X\Y\Plugin\Magento\InventoryConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Sales\GetSkuFromOrderItem"/>
</type>



<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\InventoryConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Sales;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;

/**
 * Get simple product SKU from configurable order item
 */
class GetSkuFromOrderItem
{
    /**
     * @param GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param OrderItemInterface $orderItem
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        OrderItemInterface $orderItem
    ): string {
        if ($orderItem->getProductType() !== Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            return $proceed($orderItem);
        }

        $orderItemOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
        // use object manager for now, till I override the method. 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_productloader = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
        $simple = $_productloader->create()->load($orderItemOptions['info_buyRequest']['selected_configurable_option']); 
        if($simple->getVisibility() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG){
            return $simple->getSku(); 
        }
        $sku = $orderItemOptions['simple_sku'];

        return $sku;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

decided to override:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item">
        <plugin name="X_Y_get_product_Options"  type="X\Y\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

public function aroundGetProductOptions(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $result = $proceed();
        rerurn $result;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check this link how to override the aroundExecute method https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html

Comment: already checked the link before i posted this.

Comment: you are check this link --- https://magecomp.com/blog/override-core-code-using-custom-plugin-magento-2/